# errors in dhtmlxgrid java

Tags: java, dhtmlx

I am using dhtmlxgrid but my first row doesn't get selected upon using `onRowSelect` but works fine upond using the event `onRowDblClicked` or I use keyboard navigation. But upon using keyboard nagivation and navigating to the first row, the navigation gets stuck and I cannot navigate from the first row using the keyboard but clicking on a different row works fine. Here's my code:

```
function onGraphPropGridRowSelect(id)
{
    // push the previously selected graph's data to the JSON array object
    if(lastSelectedGraphIndex != -1)
    {
        if(validateGraphProperties())
        {   
            // Note: GraphType is uneditable, so just copy existing value
            pushGraphPropertiesToJSONArr(lastSelectedGraphIndex,
                                         graphPropertiesJson[lastSelectedGraphIndex].GraphType);
        }else
        {
            definedGraphGrid.selectRow(definedGraphGrid.getRowIndex(lastSelectedGraphIndex));
            return false;
        }
    }
    // now populate the newly selected graph data to the UI elements
    populateUIElementsForSelectedGraph(id);
    // update the lastSelectedGraphIndex to the newly selected graph index
    lastSelectedGraphIndex = id;
    if (id==0){
        definedGraphGrid.enableKeyboardSupport(true);
        alert("first row selected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not available to use the "0" as an ID of the row. Please, try to use another id.